# Getting Firefox page information using JavaScript or Extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

When you right click on the Firefox to select "View page Info" and you will see the information such as

```
Modified: xxx
```

Is it possible to get this information using extension of just JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/document.shtml for all the attributes of the document object.  `document.lastModified` contains the modification date.

Answer (score 0):

The "Page Info" dialog displays the value of the [document.lastModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.lastModified) property, no "magic" involved ([prooflink](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/510300b96e62/browser/base/content/pageinfo/pageInfo.js#l530)).